# How can I pull content from Twitter, Facebook and Instagram as post items in WordPress?

Tags: facebook, twitter, wordpress

There are lots of plugins that will get Twitter / FB content and display them. I, however, want the raw content so I can style it myself. I don't want it to spit out a `ul` or whatever the formatting is by the plugin, rather I just want the raw content.

Is there a plugin or quick way to do this?

Comment: download the plugin, edit it to suit your requirements and then submit it back in to the plugin repository for others to use.

Comment: Which plugin would be the best to start with?

Comment: any of the 'lots of plugins' you've already mentioned. have a look at the ratings in the WordPress forums.

Comment: does each service's posts go into a custom post type (facebook post, twitter post) or does every post go into a single post type? How often do you want to poll? what feeds from facebook/twitter are you looking to get? single or multi user?

Comment: Single User. I'm looking to get all Facebook posts for a Public page. It should poll regularly (hourly perhaps?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just cooked up a quick plugin to get you started.

### https://github.com/fyaconiello/WP_Social_Network_Posts

what it does:

1. creates a custom post type: "social network post"
2. has a setting page for adding your facebook app_id, secret, and facebook name/id for the account timeline
3. has a cron file that will imports/updates all posts from the facebook user's timeline into posts when `php PATH_TO_PLUGIN/cron/facebook.php` is run

I didn't use wordpress scheduled events because shared hosts seem to timeout long running processes. Its better to register the sync command with the OS's cron manager. That said if a user wanted to add it as a scheduled event, the function to sync is part of the main plugin file and can be registered as an event in the epty activate/deactivate methods of the plugin.

TODO:

1. Create fields/settings to store and API information for twitter
2. Create the twitter backend / sync process (model it after the facebook one)

### EDIT

Social network posts can be accessed from the admin sidebar

[image]

Comment: How do I access the posts from WP?

Answer (score -2):

No Idea about instagram. But check out this plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oa-social-login/

It has many features. Twitter,Facebook,Linkdin,OpenID etc

Comment: Sorry, not looking to auth... I'm looking to read the posts from the social networks

Comment: Why would it require auth fr the visitor? If it's my public facebook page, then there should be no reason to auth

Comment: you will need to authenticate against the facebook/twitter api to make api requests, BUT that plugin provides authentication for end users. I think Maruf is misunderstanding the question or the purpose of the plugin he suggested.